# How to use blender through VSCode with python for integrating 2D widgets with 3D models

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting, blender, python-module

I am new to Blender community and has created some add-ons to model things through code..

However, I am failing to execute the **same code through my IDE**, IDLE and **VS Code** with all my paths set for **Python 3.7.0** installed inside *python folder of Blender 2.80 directory in C drive* (cant use other version for VS Code as Blender extension in VS Code only supports python 3.7.0 and the same Python version is compatible with only Blender 2.80)

However I have installed UPBGE in another drive with latest versions of Python(3.9.1) and Blender(2.93 Alpha)..
There, I manually installed latest version of Python like the one I had installed

So, I have my python interpreters at two following locations

> C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\python\python.exe

> D:\Softwares\UPBGE\2.93\python\python.exe

**Problems are as follows:**

1. When I check python version through command "**py --version**" it
   displays 3.9.1 even when interpreter selected as 3.7.0 in VS Code
   [selected interpreter ambiguity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iLxP.jpg)
2. Whenever I install any pypi module through cmd, it installs the
   module to older version, i.e., 3.7.0 directory in C drive even when python 3.9.1 interpreter selected
   Blender stores its built in python interpreter inside bin directory inside python folder
3. Whenever I try to run any script importing bpy stuff, it says
   **bpy** module is not present
   cannot find the module named **bpy-types**

Answer (score 0):

1. Installing python libraries into blender's python environment.

   <[Blender Python.exe path]> -m pip install <[Package Name]>

For example, in your case for UPBGE:

```
D:\Softwares\UPBGE\2.93\python\python.exe -m pip install <[Package Name]>
```

If the command fails you might need to add "pip" to you python env available here:
https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

2. For running a script that uses bpy you also need to use Blenders python.

   <[Blender Python.exe path]> <[Script Path]>